# Loading the Linux OS Kernel from BIOS

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, bios, real-mode

[From book:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466518030) After power-on, the `CPU` load the `BIOS`, build the interrupt vector table, and start interrupt service routines in real address mode. By `BIOS`, the `CPU` receives `INT 0x19`. The `ISR` of `INT 0x19` loads the first sector (512B) into the memory. This sector is the boot part of Linux which loads other parts of the OS into the memory.

The first sector is `bootsect.s`, which is written in assembly. It is the first system code that is loaded into the memory. I doubt whether assembly instructions are loaded or compiled machine instructions are loaded into memory. Does BIOS have a native `assembler` to convert assembly to machine instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the loaded sector contains compiled machine language instructions - not assembly source (.asm).

Comment: Then I would not be able to load a binary compiled for `x86` on `arm`. Does BIOS provide any platform independent booting support?

Comment: No. Why you expect anything "platform independent" in BIOS? It is the most basic level, fully dependent to hardware, etc.

Comment: Manav: INT is a x86 instruction, and so is most of the BIOS. The BIOS concept is PC/x86 (16-bit with 32-bit and 64-bit iterations) only.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: so `arm` based systems don't need `BIOS` to boot?

Comment: ARM based systems have their own BIOS. But you expect to have cross-platform boot sectors, etc. The most "universal" and crossplatform thing is a pack of versions for each platform... You cannot boot x86-specific version of Linux on ARM and for that reason there is no need from multiplatform boot sector.

Comment: They have their own startup firmware, but it is not a BIOS in the DOS sense. Usually it is some Open Firmware, Forth based customization.

Answer (score 0):

NO.  It's binary instruction codes that are loaded to memory and then executed directly.

Comment: Does Linux, Windows, Mac and other OSes also provide the binary instructions directly? I think since its boot code it should be platform independent and be converted to the CPU binary format on the fly.